# join or merge with overwrite in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to perform a join/merge/append operation on a dataframe with datetime index.

Let's say I have `df1` and I want to add `df2` to it.  `df2` can have fewer or more columns, and overlapping indexes.  For all rows where the indexes match, if `df2` has the same column as `df1`, I want the values of `df1` be overwritten with those from `df2`.

How can I obtain the desired result?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

How about: [`df2.combine_first(df1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)?

```
In [33]: df2
Out[33]: 
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-03  0.638998  1.277361  0.193649  0.345063
2000-01-04 -0.816756 -1.711666 -1.155077 -0.678726
2000-01-05  0.435507 -0.025162 -1.112890  0.324111
2000-01-06 -0.210756 -1.027164  0.036664  0.884715
2000-01-07 -0.821631 -0.700394 -0.706505  1.193341
2000-01-10  1.015447 -0.909930  0.027548  0.258471
2000-01-11 -0.497239 -0.979071 -0.461560  0.447598

In [34]: df1
Out[34]: 
                   A         B         C
2000-01-03  2.288863  0.188175 -0.040928
2000-01-04  0.159107 -0.666861 -0.551628
2000-01-05 -0.356838 -0.231036 -1.211446
2000-01-06 -0.866475  1.113018 -0.001483
2000-01-07  0.303269  0.021034  0.471715
2000-01-10  1.149815  0.686696 -1.230991
2000-01-11 -1.296118 -0.172950 -0.603887
2000-01-12 -1.034574 -0.523238  0.626968
2000-01-13 -0.193280  1.857499 -0.046383
2000-01-14 -1.043492 -0.820525  0.868685

In [35]: df2.comb
df2.combine        df2.combineAdd     df2.combine_first  df2.combineMult    

In [35]: df2.combine_first(df1)
Out[35]: 
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-03  0.638998  1.277361  0.193649  0.345063
2000-01-04 -0.816756 -1.711666 -1.155077 -0.678726
2000-01-05  0.435507 -0.025162 -1.112890  0.324111
2000-01-06 -0.210756 -1.027164  0.036664  0.884715
2000-01-07 -0.821631 -0.700394 -0.706505  1.193341
2000-01-10  1.015447 -0.909930  0.027548  0.258471
2000-01-11 -0.497239 -0.979071 -0.461560  0.447598
2000-01-12 -1.034574 -0.523238  0.626968       NaN
2000-01-13 -0.193280  1.857499 -0.046383       NaN
2000-01-14 -1.043492 -0.820525  0.868685       NaN
```

Note that it takes the values from `df1` for indices that do not overlap with `df2`. If this doesn't do exactly what you want I would be willing to improve this function / add options to it.

Comment: deinitely the best answer for merging df1 and df2, replacing the not exact matches from df1 with df2!

Answer (score 55):

For a merge like this, the `update` method of a DataFrame is useful.

Taking the examples from the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#merging-together-values-within-series-or-dataframe-columns):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 3., 5.], [-4.6, 2.1, np.nan],
                   [np.nan, 7., np.nan]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[-42.6, np.nan, -8.2], [-5., 1.6, 4]],
                   index=[1, 2])
```

Data before the `update`:

```
>>> df1
     0    1    2
0  NaN  3.0  5.0
1 -4.6  2.1  NaN
2  NaN  7.0  NaN
>>>
>>> df2
      0    1    2
1 -42.6  NaN -8.2
2  -5.0  1.6  4.0
```

Let's update `df1` with data from `df2`:

```
df1.update(df2)
```

Data after the update:

```
>>> df1
      0    1    2
0   NaN  3.0  5.0
1 -42.6  2.1 -8.2
2  -5.0  1.6  4.0
```

**Remarks:**

- It's important to notice that this is an operation "in place", modifying the DataFrame that calls `update`.
- Also note that non NaN values in `df1` are not overwritten with NaN values in `df2`

Comment: This  is more intuitive than `combine_first` because it acts exactly as the `update` method we know from dicts.

Comment: Note, that DataFrame.update() is a bit different than dict because it doesn't add new index items the same way dicts add new keys. Example: https://gist.github.com/flutefreak7/b4eb6a93565c375d79b791c2bbd672b1

Comment: you should use `update` only if you are happy to exclude indexes unique to df2

Use `combine_first` if you want to include them

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a satisfactory answer for this task yet where one does not need to pre-specify which columns should be used. I am doing it by combining `merge`, `rename`, and `drop`. `df_some_wrong` is a dataframe with important new columns. However, it has some old columns that have wrong values and should be overwritten with the correct values contained in `df_correct`. Only the columns with wrong values in `df_some_wrong` are shared between `df_some_wrong` and `df_correct`.

```py
wrong_suffix = "_wrong"
correct_suffix = "_correct"
# merge, rename shared columns with suffixes
merged_df = df_some_wrong.merge(
    df_correct.
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
    suffixes=(wrong_suffix, correct_suffix),
)
# find all the renamed columns from df_correct
rename_and_drop_cols = [
    col for col in merged_df.columns if col.endswith(correct_suffix)
]
# dict that describes how correct columns should be renamed
# to old column name
rename_cols = {
    key: key.replace(correct_suffix, "") for key in rename_and_drop_cols
}
# list describing the wrong columns that can be dropped
drop = [
    col.replace(correct_suffix, wrong_suffix) for col in rename_and_drop_cols
]
# finally rename and drop
merged_df = merged_df.rename(rename, axis=1).drop(drop, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a function, which should handle all cases (different lengths, nan values) and could be used inside an appending loop. However, it will prefer first df if data is conflicting.

```
def real_merge(df1,df2,on):
    if len(df1)==0:
        return df2
    elif len(df2)==0:
        return df1
    else:
        df3=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=on,how='outer')
        #now we have a mess to fix
        cols=[x[:-2] for x in df3.columns if x.endswith('_x')]
        for i_col in cols:
            df3.loc[:,i_col+'_x']=df3[i_col+'_x'].combine_first(df3[i_col+'_y'])
            df3.rename(columns={i_col+'_x':i_col},inplace=True)
            df3.drop(columns=[i_col+'_y'],inplace=True)
        return df3
```

Why is there no native pandas function for that? merge/update/cobmine_first are not sufficient for such a task which is requested so often on SE.