# Python pandas join on with overwrite

Tags: python, pandas

I realize this question is similar to [join or merge with overwrite in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787853/join-or-merge-with-overwrite-in-pandas), but the accepted answer does not work for me since I want to use the `on='keys'` from `df.join()`.

I have a DataFrame `df` which looks like this:

```
    keys    values
0      0  0.088344
1      0  0.088344
2      0  0.088344
3      0  0.088344
4      0  0.088344
5      1  0.560857
6      1  0.560857
7      1  0.560857
8      2  0.978736
9      2  0.978736
10     2  0.978736
11     2  0.978736
12     2  0.978736
13     2  0.978736
14     2  0.978736
```

Then I have a Series `s` (which is a result from some `df.groupy.apply()`) with the same keys:

```
keys
0       0.183328
1       0.239322
2       0.574962
Name: new_values, dtype: float64
```

Basically I want to replace the 'values' in the `df` with the values in the Series, by `keys` so every `keys` block gets the same new value. Currently, I do it as follows:

```
df = df.join(s, on='keys')
df['values'] = df['new_values']
df = df.drop('new_values', axis=1)
```

The obtained (and desired) result is then:

```
    keys    values
0      0  0.183328
1      0  0.183328
2      0  0.183328
3      0  0.183328
4      0  0.183328
5      1  0.239322
6      1  0.239322
7      1  0.239322
8      2  0.574962
9      2  0.574962
10     2  0.574962
11     2  0.574962
12     2  0.574962
13     2  0.574962
14     2  0.574962
```

That is, I add it as a new column and by using `on='keys'` it gets the corrects shape. Then I assign  `values` to be `new_values` and remove the `new_values` column. This of course works perfectly, the only problem being that I find it extremely ugly.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
df = df[df.columns[df.columns!='values']].join(s, on='keys')
```

Make sure s is named 'values' instead of 'new_values'.

To my knowledge, pandas doesn't have the ability to join with "force overwrite" or "overwrite with warning".