# Comparing two excel files with Python based on changes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables:

**Table1:**

| Name | Description | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Description123 | 123 |
| 456 | Description456 | 456 |
| 789 | Description789 | 666 |
| 101 | Description777 | 101 |
| 133 | Description133 | 133 |

**Table2:**

| Name | Description | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 456 | Description456 | 456 |
| 789 | Description789 | 789 |
| 101 | Description101 | 101 |
| 123 | Description123 | 123 |
| 102 | Description102 | 102 |

I need to find the difference in **Table1** compare it with **Table2**. The connection between these 2 Excel files will be the column **Name**.
The expected output is if something is changed in **Table 2** the data must be used from **Table 2** and if there are new rows from **Table 2** they must be added to the final result. If nothing is also changed or **Table 2** doesn't have any data for specific **Name** from **Table 1** like **133** the rows also need to be added to the final result.


**Expected output:**

| Name | Description | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Description123 | 123 |
| 456 | Description456 | 456 |
| 789 | Description789 | 789 |
| 101 | Description101 | 101 |
| 102 | Description102 | 102 |
| 133 | Description133 | 133 |

Thanks in advance!

Edit1:
I struggle to find the solution. I understand how to compare each row in the excel files, but they need to have exactly the same order in the Name column. I don't know how to do it if there is no order like this specific case above.

Comment: I struggle to find the solution. I just understand how to compare each rows in the excel files, but they need to have exactly the same order in Name column. I don't know how to do it if there is no order like this specific case above.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: As BigBen linked, and [previously answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9794891/7891382), you will need to set_index

Comment: @greg - it was not a rude comment. Unfortunately SO sees many low-quality questions that equate to "give me some code" please and demonstrate no attempt to solve the problem. Since this is not a code-writing service, it's best to demonstrate what you've tried, otherwise it *seems* like you're just asking for code, even if that's not your intention. See [ask] and [reprex] for further reading.