# Concatenate dataframes that may have dates in common

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an initial DataFrame, lets call it `df` that looks like:

```
|date        |Colombia   |Peru   |Argentina   |Chile   |Brazil   |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|2020-09-26  |3          |5      |1           |4        |2       |
|2020-09-27  |5          |5      |1           |2        |3       |
|2020-09-28  |3          |1      |2           |6        |5       |
|2020-09-29  |1          |6      |1           |2        |4       |
|2020-09-30  |1          |7      |1           |2        |0       |
```

```
{'Colombia': {'2020-09-26': 3, '2020-09-27': 5, '2020-09-28': 3, '2020-09-29': 1, '2020-09-30': 1}, 
 'Peru': {'2020-09-26': 5.0, '2020-09-27': 5.0, '2020-09-28': 1.0, '2020-09-29': 6.0, '2020-09-30': 7.0}, 
 'Argentina': {'2020-09-26': 1.0, '2020-09-27': 1.0, '2020-09-28': 2.0, '2020-09-29': 1.0, '2020-09-30': 1.0}, 
 'Chile': {'2020-09-26': 4.0, '2020-09-27': 2.0, '2020-09-28': 6.0, '2020-09-29': 2.0, '2020-09-30': 2.0}, 
 'Brazil': {'2020-09-26': 2.0, '2020-09-27': 3.0, '2020-09-28': 5.0, '2020-09-29': 4.0, '2020-09-30': 0.0}}
```

And I have to concatenate it with several DataFrames for each country, that may or may not have common with `df`, let's call one in particular `df2`, that looks like:

```
|             |Colombia |
------------------------
|datetime     |         |
-------------------------
|2020-10-01   |4        |
|2020-10-02   |2        |
|2020-10-03   |3        |
|2020-10-04   |5        |
|2020-10-05   |1        |
|2020-10-06   |0        |
```

```
{'Colombia': {'2020-10-01': 4, '2020-10-02': 2, '2020-10-03': 3, '2020-10-04': 5, '2020-10-05': 1, '2020-10-06': 0}}
```

All the DataFrames are indexed by dates.

I need that, if it would exist in the DataFrames as `df2` a date that is already in `df`, put the value that is already in `df` and in another case to concatenate the two DataFrame and put the dates that are in df2 with their respective value.

This is what I tried:

```
dates_ind = numpy.in1d(df2.index, df.index)
    if numpy.any(dates_ind):
        df.loc[df2.index[dates_ind]][df2.columns[0]] = df2.loc[dates_ind].values.flatten()

    else:
        df = pd.concat([df, df2.loc[~dates_ind]], axis=0).drop_duplicates(keep="first")
```

But the problem is that it puts `NaN` on dates that are not in the initial DataFrame, `df`, for example:

```
|date        |Colombia   |Peru   |Argentina   |Chile   |Brazil   |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|2020-09-26  |3          |5      |1           |4        |2       |
|2020-09-27  |5          |5      |1           |2        |3       |
|2020-09-28  |3          |1      |2           |6        |5       |
|2020-09-29  |1          |6      |1           |2        |4       |
|2020-09-30  |1          |7      |1           |2        |0       |
|2020-10-01  |NA         |NA     |NA          |NA       |NA      |
|2020-10-02  |NA         |NA     |NA          |NA       |NA      |
|2020-10-03  |NA         |NA     |NA          |NA       |NA      |
|2020-10-04  |NA         |NA     |NA          |NA       |NA      |
|2020-10-05  |NA         |NA     |NA          |NA       |NA      |
|2020-10-06  |NA         |NA     |NA          |NA       |NA      |
```

I also tried this line of code

```
df = pd.concat([df, df2.loc[~dates_ind]], axis=0).drop_duplicates(keep="first")
```

Remove the `~`, but what it did not  put the dates that are in the `df2` and not in `df`:

```
|date        |Colombia   |Peru   |Argentina   |Chile   |Brazil   |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|2020-09-26  |3          |5      |1           |4        |2       |
|2020-09-27  |5          |5      |1           |2        |3       |
|2020-09-28  |3          |1      |2           |6        |5       |
|2020-09-29  |1          |6      |1           |2        |4       |
|2020-09-30  |1          |7      |1           |2        |0       |
```

And I don't know what to do anymore.... Can you guys help me?

Comment: Yes, date is the index of both dataframes

Comment: You may find helpful answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787853/join-or-merge-with-overwrite-in-pandas

Comment: You want to `pd.merge()`, not `pd.concat` (concat just puts the dataframes next to each other, while merging operates depending on whether specific columns or index are equal)