# concat two df without any duplicate values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, merge, concatenation

I want to join two dataframe (i.e df_1, df_2) based on date so that a new df_1_2 formed with column as Date, A, B, C where all dates with their resppective values are present without any duplicate value

Current code:

```
import pandas as pd

# create dictionary

dict1 = {"Date":["2000-01-01", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-07"], "A":[99, 93,100,97], "B": [106,107,109,105]}
dict2 = {"Date":["2000-01-01", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-07"], "A":[99, 96,100,97], "B": [106,100,109,105], "C":[2,5,8,4]}

# create dataframe using dict1

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df_1["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_1["Date"])
df_1.set_index("Date", inplace = True)

# create dataframe using dict2

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
df_2["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_2["Date"])
df_2.set_index("Date", inplace = True)

# concat df_1 & df_2

df_1_2 = pd.concat([df_1, df_2])
print(df_1_2)
```

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: try checking `combine_first` function. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [join or merge with overwrite in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787853/join-or-merge-with-overwrite-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Emma's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2956135/emma) [solution of using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76829996/concat-two-df-without-any-duplicate-values/76830602#76830602:%7E:text=try%20checking%20combine_first,29%20mins%20ago) `combine_first` is the most straight forward and most likely the best:

```
df_1.combine_first(df_2)
```

You can also look into [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). Is there a reason you have to set Date as the index in the first portion? Regardless, if you reset the indexes, merge them on `Date`, `A`, and `B` via `outer` join and then set the index back to `Date`, you can get the same result as `combine_first`. Just an alternative for more options:

```
(df_1.reset_index().merge(df_2.reset_index(), on = ['Date', 'A', 'B'], how = 'outer')
 .set_index('Date')
 .sort_index())
```

Output for both:

```
             A   B   C
Date            
2000-01-01  99  106 2.0
2000-01-03  96  100 5.0
2000-01-04  93  107 NaN
2000-01-05  100 109 8.0
2000-01-07  97  105 4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Do I get this right?

- By duplicates, you mean identical rows regardless 'C'
- In case of such duplicate, you would like to keep the row from df_2 because it has extra information ('C')

If that is correct, because those are not duplicates over all columns,

- do the concatenation as you did `df_1_2 = pd.concat([df_1, df_2])`
- then handle your duplicates (mark rows, then remove)

```
# Make sure rows from df_1_2 are place on top
df_1_2.sort_values(by='C', inplace=True)

# Mark duplicates with regards to 'A' and 'B'
df_1_2['duplicate'] = df_1_2.drop(['C'], axis=1).duplicated()
```

Intermediate output:

```py
              A    B    C  duplicate
Date                                
2000-01-01   99  106  2.0      False
2000-01-07   97  105  4.0      False
2000-01-03   96  100  5.0      False
2000-01-05  100  109  8.0      False
2000-01-01   99  106  NaN       True
2000-01-04   93  107  NaN      False
2000-01-05  100  109  NaN       True
2000-01-07   97  105  NaN       True
```

```
# Remove duplicates, drop 'duplicate' temporary column, then restore order by date (index). 
df_1_2.loc[~df_1_2.duplicate].drop('duplicate', axis=1).sort_index()
```

Output:

```py
              A    B    C
Date                     
2000-01-01   99  106  2.0
2000-01-03   96  100  5.0
2000-01-04   93  107  NaN
2000-01-05  100  109  8.0
2000-01-07   97  105  4.0
```